# Default WordPress .htaccess rewrites causes default server page to load due to no default index page present for the root URL

Tags: linux, apache-2.4, .htaccess, redirect, wordpress

I could really do with some help here please. I know this is a WordPress issue now through testing.
If I allow .htaccess to process rewrites on my Wordpress sites by adding `AllowOverride FileInfo` to the https conf file, my WordPress sites all redirect to the AlmaLinux default page due to no default index page present for the root URL. If I don't allow it to process the .htaccess it works but I need to use .htaccess
**What is going on here?**

Here is my WordPress site `.htaccess` file that would get processed if I uncomment `AllowOverride FileInfo` and then it breaks WordPress by redirecting everything to the AlmaLinux default page.
This is created by WordPress itself

```
# BEGIN WordPress
# The directives (lines) between "BEGIN WordPress" and "END WordPress" are
# dynamically generated, and should only be modified via WordPress filters.
# Any changes to the directives between these markers will be overwritten.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Thank you so much in advance for anyone who can dig me out of this.

Answer (score 1):

FIXED
I should have looked in Apache error logs in the first place.
I just did and found:

```
[Wed Mar 29 23:17:59.234743 2023] [rewrite:error] [pid 133333:tid 133444] [client 81.11.11.11:53583] AH00670: Options FollowSymLinks and SymLinksIfOwnerMatch are both off, so the RewriteRule directive is also forbidden due to its similar ability to circumvent directory restrictions : /var/www/www.mysite.com/
```

Doing a search for the error we see:
If your server is set with both FollowSymLinks and SymLinksIfOwnerMatch off, then rewrite rules will stop working

Simple as that!

So I went through all my sites in the Apache conf files and changed:
`Options None`
to:
`Options SymLinksIfOwnerMatch`

Fixed